# User can have many 'foo' but only one per 'bar' in existance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

The best way to explain what I'm asking is this:

User can have as many foo as they like, 
there can exist as many bar as needed,
BUT user can only have ONE foo per bar.

How do I enforce this in the model?

Because I had a check in the controller but apparently that's not a good idea as this is a model constraint that should be on the model rather then in the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the foo model add:

```
 before_validation :set_bar
 validates :user_id, uniqueness: {  scope:  :bar_id,message: "Only one foo per bar please" }

 def set_bar
   self.bar ||= bar.current
   true
end
```

It works by checking the user_id with the scope of bar_id for the linked bar entry   to check if a link exists between them all, if there is one then the user has a 'foo' for that particular 'bar' and so the new entry won't be created (it will error)

At least that's how I understand it, perhaps some one with more understanding can better explain it then me, but it does exactly what I want it to do.

You have to make sure that the bar_id is set before you validate otherwise you get nil errors

but that pretty much enforces "one per other" constraint.

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :bar

...

end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :user
has_one :foo

...

end
```

Comment: And you would access it like 'User.bar.foo' ?

Comment: Not what I was after but thanks any way, I appreciate your help none the less, I will post the answer I found in a moment.

Comment: Since I can't edit, I'll post this here, I do have an answer but I can't post it yet, need to wait 8 hours, I'll post an answer tommorow as I don't have access to internet at home for the moment